# Dots until price in menu item

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make list of dishes in menu and I need to make dots until price from description. I want this to look like this
[image]

And also if description is too long like this

[image]

There is my code

```
<div className="container-fluid">
        {dishes
          .filter(dish => dish.category.id === props.category.id)
          .map(dish => (
            <div key={dish.id}>
              <div className="row">
                <h1 className="dish-title">{dish.name[state.lang]}</h1>
              </div>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col px-0">
                  {dish.description[state.lang] && <div className="dish-desc m-0">{dish.description[state.lang]}</div>}
                </div>
                <div className="col-auto">
                  <DishSizes
                    sizes={dish.sizes}
                    containerClassName="d-flex flex-column"
                    priceClassName="dish-price px-1"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
```

Im mapping my json file, this is just dishes section, that renders all dishes. DishSizes is basically component that renders prices of dish. Do you guys have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Maybe this should be a pure CSS question. Using real textual dots will be harder, and will break on screen resize unless you recalculate everything

Comment: you can create a pseudo element and use `border: 1px dotted`

Comment: border doesn't work :( also I need it to work when description is too long

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a dotted border.

```css
main {
  width: 35em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: inherit;
}

.sub {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.desc {
  flex: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.desc span {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Club Sandwich with Extra Flavor</h1>
  <div class="sub">
    <div class="desc">
      <span>
      Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet ham hock chuck ribeye short ribs, biltong kevin kielbasa meatloaf shoulder corned beef spare ribs leberkas tenderloin.  &nbsp;<span></div>
    <div class="price">5 EUR</div>
  </div>
</>
```

Comment: It works, thank you, the only problem is that this dotted border is like 1px under comparing to the desc and it doesn't look that good, is there any way to make it look better?

Comment: The idea is that the white span in the desc block hides the border under the text. You will  need to fiddle with the CSS to make it look better if things don't quite align.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.price-display {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.item-name {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}

.price-separator {
  flex: 1;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #999;
  margin: 0.6em 5px 0;
}

.item-price {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="price-display">
  <span class="item-name">Artikelname</span>
  <span class="price-separator"></span>
  <span class="item-price">99,99 &euro;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to this answer. How does it differ from the accepted answer posted 2 years ago?